# Configurar la instalacion homestead para laravel

Tags: laravel

Ya instalé casi todo, instalé vagrant y corre, también virtualbox pero estoy entrampado en la configuración del archivo homestead.yaml, no sé si crear ni donde la carpeta code. El instructor hizo crear unas claves con PuTTY pero al final no las usa, la verdad que es un enredo.

```html
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/homesteadKey.pub

<!--estas son las claves creadas con Putty-->

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/homesteadKeyPrivate.ppk

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/dev/php/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: equipos-dentales.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/equipos-dentales/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Pero luego continua con el mismo archivo homestead.yaml asi:

```html
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/dev/php/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: equipos-dentales.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/equipos-dentales/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Otra duda es que al continuar no usa las claves que se generaron anteriormente en Putty, otra duda también es que no sé si debo crear la carpeta code y en donde crearla.

Al continuar el video el tutor  ejecuta un cd /home/vagrant/code pero la máquina no reconoce el file, por favor me pudieran ayudar a terminar la configuracion. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La carpeta donde se va a montar Homestead se configura en la sentencia `folder` del archivo de Homestead.yaml. Es decir, en **map** pondrás la ruta a la carpeta en tu ordenador, terminando en la carpeta code y luego to lo dejas como está.

En tu caso esta así:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/dev/php/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

Y con eso debería bastar. Una vez hayas hecho `vagrant up`, haz `vagrant ssh` y estaras en el directorio donde se encuentre la carpeta code, haz `cd code\` y ya estaría.

Comment: hola, debo crear manualmente la carpeta code o al ejecutar,  la carpeta se creará automaticamente?

Comment: si no la tienes creada, la tienes que crear tú a mano.